# R: Quantmod to pull S&P Index with ^ symbol before ticker

Tags: r, quantmod

I am having trouble using the quantmod package to get info on the S&P (ticker = ^GSPC).

For a normal stock (example: DFS) I'd be able to run the below code:

```
start <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2020-05-06")
getSymbols("DFS", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
DFS <-  data.frame(date=index(DFS), coredata(DFS))
head(DFS)
```

The problem I have with the S&P is the ^ symbol in the name.

```
start <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2020-05-06")
getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
SP500 <-  data.frame(date=index(^GSPC), coredata(^GSPC))
```

This code gives the following error:
*Error: unexpected '^' in "SP500 <-  data.frame(date=index(^"*

Does anyone know a good work around for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `auto.assign = FALSE`. This allows you to assign your values to your own `data.frame` with a more appropriate name.

```
start <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2020-05-06")
df <- quantmod::getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end, auto.assign = FALSE)
```

as a side note, this will also be the default behaviour in a future update of  `quantmod`.

Comment: There is no reason to use `auto.assign = FALSE` as `get.Symbols` takes care of the caret and deletes it, when assigning the name. so "^GSPC" becomes "GSPC". You triggered an error because you tried to operate on an object with a caret in its name which is not allowed in R.